# What is the difference in these Linux path

Tags: linux, path

What is differs in Linux path

```
   /etc/passwd
 ../etc/passwd
/../etc/passwd
```

are these path same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/passwd` is the same as `/../etc/passwd` in recent Linux kernels.

The [LVS](http://tldp.org/LDP/khg/HyperNews/get/fs/vfstour.html) automatically adds entries for `"."` and `".."` to directories and, for `"/"`, they both point to `"/"`'s inode.

`../etc/passwd` it's a relative path, so it depends on the process current working directory.
If the cwd is `"/"` or `"/etc"`, then they all point to the same file.

See also: [Canonicalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization)

Comment: The Linux `realpath` utility gives the real canonical path of a given file.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is an absolute path. Any path beginning with / is absolute and it contains all the directories required to reach the file.

the second one is a relative path. '..' is a special directory that means the parent of the current one. If you are currently in /etc/X11 folder, for example, ../etc/passwd will mean to go up one folder (to /etc) and the file passwd will be there.

The last one is strange. The root directory '/' doesn't have a parent, but it still has '..' folder inside. If you make a 'cd' to .. inside '/' nothing happens, so this works pretty much the same way as the first opton (/etc/passwd), but it looks rather confusing.

Answer (score 2):

First is an absolute path. Consider it like the real exact location.

Second is relative, and depends from where you are.
If your current directory is

```
/home/user/
```

Then `../etc/passwd` would be located at :
   `/home/etc/passwd`

As for the last one, it doesn't make sense, since / is the root of every folder. It's basically the same as `/home/etc/passwd`

Comment: the last one is wrong - there is no `..` in the root directory.

Comment: @wroniasty: yes there is. It points to /. The last one and first one refer to the same file.

Comment: so why when i trying to read file from browser with link www.host.com/?id=/etc/passwd i get passwd file, but when i use link www.host.com/?id=../etc/passwd i can't access that file. Why?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve looks dangerous. But my guess is that your server starts from its www folder. which is not /www/ (right?)

Comment: @dmitrij-holkin: applications (especially public facing ones) sanitize their inputs in order to mitigate directory traversal attacks.